# Upload file from android to tomcat server

Tags: android, servlets, tomcat7

Here is my sample android code(client end) to upload file in the server. In the server end i use .php code to upload data that are also given below. Now i am using tomcat server and need to convert the server end code into Servlet code. What will be the tentative code?

```
 public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

    String fileName = sourceFileUri;
       HttpURLConnection conn = null;
       DataOutputStream dos = null;  
       String lineEnd = "\r\n";
       String twoHyphens = "--";
       String boundary = "*****";
       int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
       byte[] buffer;
       int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
       File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

       if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

           dialog.dismiss(); 

           Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                               +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
               }
           }); 
          finish();
           return 0;

       } else
       {
           try { 

                 // open a URL connection to the Servlet
               FileInputStream fileInputStream = new     FileInputStream(sourceFile);
               URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

               // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
               conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
               conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
               conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
               conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
               conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
               conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
               conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

               dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                         + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               // create a buffer of  maximum size
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

               // read file and write it into form...
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

               while (bytesRead > 0) {

                 dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                }

               // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

               // Responses from the server (code and message)
               serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
               String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

               if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                   Toast.makeText(Confirm.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });                
               }    

               //close the streams //
               sourceFile.delete();
               filecheckdel();
               fileInputStream.close();
               dos.flush();
               dos.close();

          } catch (MalformedURLException ex) { } 
          catch (Exception e) {} 

          dialog.dismiss();  
          finish();
          return serverResponseCode; 

        } // End else block 
      }
```

PHP code-

```
$file_path = "images/";

$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}
```

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit your question appropriately.  As it stands, the question is far too broad, and you don't present any effort at solving the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to give ui part then u can skip the jsp page only part will do the job.

and one more thing use async task for executing network operations runonuithread is not a good approach for performing network operations.

See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm)